# QT printing binary tree instruction messages

Tags: c++, qt, binary-tree

I am having an issue trying to display correct debugging messages in my GUI on qt.  I am implementing a binary tree based on words that are entered by a user.  And for each word that is entered an appropriate debugging message should display.

For example:

- user enters : `a`
- then user enters `b`
- debugging message `word is greater than a`

The problem that I am having is that if the user was to then type a third word in the debugging message is incorrect.

- user enters `c`
- debugging message still displays as `word is greater than a`

But I would like it to display `word is greater than b` instead.

If the user inputs a duplicate word the message should display `'word' has already been detected`.  This message only works if its the original word that the user has entered and is duplicating.  For the example above if the user enters `a` again the correct message appears.  If they enter `b` again the duplicate message does not appear.

How can I fix this?

```
QStringList tree::VerboseModeinsert(NodePtr &ptr, QString aWord)
{

    aWord.remove(QRegExp("[[]"));
    aWord.remove(QRegExp("[]]"));

    if(!(aWord.contains(QRegExp("[0123456789]"))))
    {
    aWord = aWord.toLower();
    if(ptr != NULL)
    {
        if(aWord < ptr->word)
        {
            insert(ptr->below, aWord);
            QString a = "Word is less than ";
            QString b = ptr->word;
            verboseList << a + b;
        }
        else if(aWord > ptr->word)
        {
            insert(ptr->above, aWord);
            QString a = "Word is greater than ";
            QString b = ptr->word;
            verboseList << a + b;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr->occurence++;
            QString c = " has already been detected";
            verboseList << aWord + c;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ptr = new WordTree;
        ptr->word = aWord;
        ptr->below = NULL;
        ptr->above = NULL;
        ptr->occurence = 1;
    }
}
return verboseList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you forgot to update the pointer to the last inserted,

Try this:

```
        ...
        if(aWord < ptr->word)
        {
            ...
            ptr = ptr->below;
        }
        else if(aWord > ptr->word)
        {
            ...
            ptr = ptr->above;
        }
        ...
```

PS: I'm not completly sure what I'm doing beacause you don'n provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I think the post is suficient to infer that you are not changing the pointer to the last inserted.